# HttpClient queries on main thread keeps crashing when in Runnable

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpclient, runnable

I've expierenced this code runs smoothly on *Android 2.2*. But on *Android 4.0* it crashes.

I am assuming that, It's caused by **HttpClient**. So I moved the code into a **Runnable**, but it keeps crashing.

```
new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {        
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(new URI(serverroot + URI_ARGS));
                client.execute(request);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.run();
```

Is there another way to do this without using **AsyncTask**?

Comment: can you provide the logcat of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from [API11](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) there is new exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException` that will be thrown if you are working with network on UI thread, so you need to move you code out of UI Thread. `Runnable` is just interface it won't help you without actually `Thread`.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(serverroot + URI_ARGS));
            client.execute(request);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: @MatoKormuth Actually you need to start new thread, that will perform operation out of UI thread. This code can be used if you don't want to interact with UI, otherwise use `AsyncTask` that also create separate thread and give you convenient way to interact with UI.